# Where's my room in Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it the one to right from main entrance to the apartments on the 1st floor? I've somehow missed the explanation where's exactly my room. That one at least doesn't say "Steal from" when I point to containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can't remember, your room is most easily detected by the bed.  All the other beds will say "Sleep (Owned)" - yours will not.

An important note - there will often be people hanging out in your room (Jzargo seems to frequent mine).

Comment: If you have a problem with people hanging out in your room, you should probably stop barging into theirs, putting buckets on their heads, and making off with all their valuables.

Answer (score 5):

Your room in the college of Winterhold is the first room to the right when you enter the Hall of Attainment on the ground floor.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes it is.**

If you want to be sure open the console(tilde key) click on wardrobe to select it and type            **IsOwner** you should see to who it belongs exactly.